# perl string match issues

Tags: regex, perl

i have a script in which i need to skip comments, and i am able to achieve it partially...

```
IN :

{****************************
{test : test...test }

Script:

if ( $data =~  m/(^{\*+$)/ ){
}
```

With the above match i am able to identify the comment and skip it to get the next line..

```
Out:
{test : test...test }
```

If the same comment consists of any space or any character in the place of *, my match fails..

```
IN:
{** *****    or   {* abccd   or {*abce
```

All the above cases are failed to skip ...
What might be worng in the match,...can any one help me out..

Answer (score 1):

The `$` in your regex is an anchor that denotes the end of the string/line, which insists that the match will happen only when you have a row full of `*`s after the initial `{`

Removing this anchor will allow all three cases to match:

```
for ( '{*********', '{** *****', ,'{* abccd' , '{*abce' ) {

    print "$_ Matches\n" if /^{\*+/;
}
```

Comment: i tried to remove the anchor but i do get an error...saying.. "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string"

Comment: @NEW : Is the line number corresponding to the regex match, or is it another line?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what the syntax for comments is in your text, but given the examples, I'm going to *assume* that `{*` at the beginning of a line, followed by anything until the end of the line, is a comment.

In that case, your regex `/(^{\*+$)/` won't work. That says:

1. `^` - Match the beginning of the line
2. `{` - Match a `{`
3. `\*+` - Match one or more `*`s
4. `$` - Match the end of the line

This pattern won't match if anything else comes between the `*`s and the end of the line.

Something like `/^{\*.+$/` should do what you want. That changes your pattern to match one or more non-newline characters (the `.`) until you reach the end of the line.

Comment: i tried using the same but i do get an error...saying.. "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string"

Comment: That warning (not error) is unrelated to the particular regex you might be using. Figure out what value is undefined and define it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow some other characters behind `{*` part, then just remove `$` from the pattern.

This is a simple **Perl code** that you can start with:

```
@data = <main::DATA>;
print map { $_ if !/^{\*+/ } @data;

__DATA__
{****************************
{test : test...test}
```

**Output**:

```
{test : test...test}
```

*Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/DWKp3).*